# Bitwise operations: shifting 31 bits to the right. Is this a bug?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an uint:

2147483648 (only 32nd bit is turned on)

which in binary is:

1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

Now if I shift this number 31 bits to right, the result should be 1, shouldn't it?

However I get this value back: 4294967295

binary:

1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111

I wrote this unit test:

```
[Test]
public function testShift(): void {

    // shift 31st bit 30 bits to the right -> WORKS!!!
    var bit31:uint = 1073741824;  // 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
    var test1:uint = bit31 >> 30;
    assertEquals(1, test1);

    // shift 32nd bit 31 bits to the right -> FAILS!!!
    var bit32:uint = 2147483648; // 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
    var test2:uint = bit32 >> 31;
    assertEquals(1, test2);
}
```

Can someone please enlighten me?

Thanks!

**** EDIT ****

Here is the unit test output:

expected:<1> but was:<4294967295>

**** EDIT 2 ****

For a while I thought I was loosing my sanity.
I tried the same using c#. Here is a [link](http://csharppad.com/) to an online interactive shell).

```
UInt32 token = 2147483648;
UInt32 result = token >> 31;
Console.Write(result);
```

Using c# the result is 1. As expected...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out, had to use the unsigned shift operator >>> instead of >>